# Issue submitting wysiwyg data through Ajax

Tags: ajax, wysiwyg

I am Using Cl Editor On a Cms in a working on, Everytime i submit data through ajax i am having problems with it.

Let's say i write 10 lines in my wysiwyg editor but i only receive 3 or 4 in php, after some debugging in firebug what i have noticed is the html i am sending through ajax contains a span with class "Apple-converted-space" `<span class="Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span>` i am able to get everything before this span, but the text after this span is missing. I have no idea what it is. Let me write my code for better understanding.

**To get cleditor data**

```
var data = $(".cleditorMain iframe").contents().find('body').html();
```

**Ajax Form Submission**

```
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == '4' && xmlhttp.status == '200')
        {
        }
    }
    parameters = 'data=' + data
    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'libs/make_procedure.php', true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send(parameters);
    return true;
```

I have also tried jquery ajax method.. same problem exists there, so please do not ask me to use the other way to submit data via ajax.

Thanks

Comment: `onreadystatechange` looks very broken, what is the code suppose to do?

Comment: @leppie onreadystatechange is for the response and i am not worried about that .. the issue is the data i am sending through ajax is breaking after a span with class "Apple-converted-space"

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check whether it is javascript that is not sending correct data or your backend that is not able to receive it.

So first you should debug in javascript by writing an alert(data); statement right after you get the data from that cieditor control, and see what do you get there. Use Firefox and you can also copy the html using mouse pointer from the alert box. (which is not possible in IE)

You should also check the cieditor specs to see if there is any easier way to get data in javascript.

You may also want to consider using CKEditor.

Answer (score 0):

You are posting the data without escaping the contents of the data. Since the & is the seperator for different fields in a post, data will contain only the part up untill the first &. Use encodeURIComponent to escape the data value.

Change the line

parameters = 'data=' + data

to

parameters = 'data=' + encodeURIComponent(data);

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent